# DotNet5 Hangfire microservice running on multiple servers

Tags: .net-core, hangfire

We have a microservice having hangfire scheduler deployed in multiple server environment. Currently the hangfire gets triggers from all 3 servers simultaneously resulting in duplication of process on all 3 servers. Is there any way to restrict the hangfire job to be execute only on 1 server at a time?

Answer (score 0):

In your web application, code logic to enable hangfire only on one physical server. This is what I have in my startup.cs (run when application restarts),

```
// if "isHangfireOn" = 1 inside web.config, enable hangfire on server.
// ONLY one physical server should run with this setting enabled. 
if (("1".Equals(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["isHangfireOn"].ToString())))
{
    //Specify the use of Sqlserver for timed task persistence
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("hangfireconfig");

    //enable server
    app.UseHangfireServer();

    //enable Dashboard panel
    app.UseHangfireDashboard();

    //Cyclic execution of tasks
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Email.SendEmail(), Cron.Daily(amHour, amMins), TimeZoneInfo.Local);
}
```

Then in your web.config, enable "isHangfireOn" on ONE server only. Disable it for any other servers.